# Get XML node children using a variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

Given the following file:

```
<environments>
  <dev>
    <property1>23</property1>
    <property2>blue</property2>
    <property3>apple</property3>
  </dev>
  <prod>
    <property1>27</property1>
    <property2>red</property2>
    <property3>orange</property3>
  </prod>
</environments>
```

And the following code:

```
$environmentsFile = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content "environments.xml");
$envs = $environmentsFile.environments;

$envName = "prod"
```

How would I access the "prod" children and iterate through them?  I'm already iterating through the environments using `ForEach ($env in $envs.ChildNodes) {}` and I know I oculd do `$envs.prod`

I tried this:

```
$test = $envs.SelectNodes("//$envName")
ForEach ($ele in $test) {
    Write-Host $ele.value
}
```

But it didn't output anything. Inspecting reveals that it looks like `$test` has a single node that contains all the nodes I want, so I tried `$test[0]` and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had done a couple things wrong.  This functions as desired:

```
$test = $envs.SelectNodes("//$envName")[0]
ForEach ($ele in $test.ChildNodes) {
    Write-Host "$($ele.Name): $($ele.InnerText)"
}
```